# How to make auto increament folder?

Tags: c#, directory, auto-increment

I have tried how to make auto increment folder, but there is a problem when numbering, does anyone know where is the problem?

```
public void NewFolder()
        {
            try
            {
                string FolderName = Path.Combine(txtOutputFileEn.Text, txtNamaFile.Text);
                tempFolder = FolderName;
                if (!Directory.Exists(tempFolder))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(tempFolder);
                }
                else if (Directory.Exists(tempFolder))
                {
                    tempFolder = tempFolder + ("001");
                    if (!Directory.Exists(tempFolder))
                    {
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(tempFolder);
                    }
                    else if (Directory.Exists(tempFolder)) 
                    {
                        int x = 1;
                        for (x = 0; x < 50; x++)
                        {
                            string angkaString = tempFolder.Substring(tempFolder.Length - 3);
                            int angka = Convert.ToInt32(angkaString) + x;
                            string angka00 = "00" + angka.ToString();
                            tempFolder = FolderName + angka00.Substring(angka00.Length - 3);
                            if (!Directory.Exists(tempFolder))
                            {
                                Directory.CreateDirectory(tempFolder);
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                MessageBox.Show(tempFolder);
            }
            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(this, ex.Message, Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
```

> Here is output the name folder =
>   folder001,folder002,folder004,folder007,folder11,folder16,folder22.
>
> I want make the name = folder001,folder002,folder003,folder004.. next

Comment: your problem: `int angka = Convert.ToInt32(angkaString) + x;` means `1+1=2; 2+2=4; 4+3=7; 7+4=11`... etc.

Comment: @Bolu I think I have to restore the value of x by adding x = 1, where the code should I change?

Comment: use `int angka = Convert.ToInt32(angkaString) + 1;` See Shahrooz Jefri ㇱ's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
                    int angka = Convert.ToInt32(angkaString) + x;
```

Use this:

```
                    int angka = Convert.ToInt32(angkaString) + 1;
```

Comment: Repeating answers that have already been given but in a much clearer way without the unnecessary repetition of the rest of the code. Definite +1 for clarity. :)

Comment: Even though this is the correct answer, please have a look at @Douglas' solution below... I must say that the code you've written is quite convoluted and overly complex.

Answer (score 2):

I've cleaned up your code to get the functionality you're after:

```
public void NewFolder()
{
    try
    {
        string folderName = Path.Combine(txtOutputFileEn.Text, txtNamaFile.Text);
        if (!Directory.Exists(folderName))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(folderName);
        }
        else
        {
            for (int x = 1; x < 50; x++)
            {
                string tempFolder = folderName + x.ToString().PadLeft(3, '0');
                if (!Directory.Exists(tempFolder))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(tempFolder);
                    MessageBox.Show(tempFolder);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(this, ex.Message, Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

> int angka = Convert.ToInt32(angkaString) + x; instead of adding **x**
>   here you can add **1** directly

```
public void NewFolder()
        {
            try
            {
                string FolderName = Path.Combine(txtOutputFileEn.Text, txtNamaFile.Text);
                tempFolder = FolderName;
                if (!Directory.Exists(tempFolder))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(tempFolder);
                }
                else if (Directory.Exists(tempFolder))
                {
                    tempFolder = tempFolder + ("001");
                    if (!Directory.Exists(tempFolder))
                    {
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(tempFolder);
                    }
                    else if (Directory.Exists(tempFolder)) 
                    {
                        int x = 1;
                        for (x = 0; x < 50; x++)
                        {
                            string angkaString = tempFolder.Substring(tempFolder.Length - 3);
                            int angka = Convert.ToInt32(angkaString) + 1;
                            string angka00 = "00" + angka.ToString();
                            tempFolder = FolderName + angka00.Substring(angka00.Length - 3);
                            if (!Directory.Exists(tempFolder))
                            {
                                Directory.CreateDirectory(tempFolder);
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                MessageBox.Show(tempFolder);
            }
            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(this, ex.Message, Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -2):

You code style is not very clear. You should use good names for you methods, variables etc.
Naming is very important.

A good solution is to use string formatting provided by the `.ToString()` method.
I fixed up and simplified your code:

```
    public void NewFolder()
    {
        try
        {
            string folderName = Path.Combine(txtOutputFileEn.Text, txtNamaFile.Text);

            if (!Directory.Exists(folderName))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(folderName);
            }
            else
            {
                // Creates 50 folder from 001 up to 050
                // This works also if we have folders from 001 up 022 allready. It will extend up to 050
                for (int i = 1; i <= 50; i++)
                {
                    // formatting the string for 3 digits like 001, 002 and so on.
                    string angka00 = i.ToString("D3");

                    var folderWithNumber = folderName + angka00;
                    if (!Directory.Exists(folderWithNumber))
                    {
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(folderWithNumber);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(this, ex.Message, Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What? Reformatting code never fixes bugs... I'm not going to compare your code line by line but if you expect this to have fixed the problem I'm sure the solution must have been more than to use formatting... (and at a glance the bug looks like it is still there...

Comment: It isn't about formatting the code. It's about to use the `ToString()` method to format the output of the int to string conversion. Read my code pls.

Comment: You have a ton of code quoted. You should actually make clear in your answer what your solution is (as you now have) and not expect people to make a line by line comparison of your code to find what your fix is. As it is I still don't understand why you think this will fix it. If `angka` is coming through as 4 instead of 3 then I am pretty sure `ToString` won't help you with that. Feel free to explain why I am wrong though.

Comment: I fixed my code. Now it is simpler and faster. Sorry for that.